# How do I use the modf function in Metal Shading Language?

Tags: c, floating-point, metal

I need to separate the decimal part of a `float` from the integer part. In C, I can use `modf` to achieve this. When I try to use the same function in Metal Shading Language, it returns the following error:

> No matching function for call to 'modf'
>
> Fix in metal_math

Pressing "Fix in metal_math" only causes more issues in the metal_math file. Is there some way that I can use `modf` or an alternate method to get just the decimal part in Metal Shading Language. Here is my code so far in Metal Shading Language.

```
float f = <some float of undetermined precision>;
float decimal;
modf(f, &decimal);
```

Comment: What happens when you `#include <metal_math>`? It has this function: `METAL_FUNC float modf(float x, thread float &intval)` so it should be fine for floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass your value by reference, not by address.
Replace your code with this:

```
modf(f, decimal);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it fixed the issue. Just one more question, is there any way that I can get the decimal part as an Integer?

Comment: @Todd What would that mean? If your input value was 1.234, would you expect an integer that was 234? If so, what would happen if your input was 1.23?

Comment: @TimRandall Yes, if the input is 1.234, I would like an integer that is 234. For 1.23, it would be 23.